# protobuf-net : could not create instance of abstract class

Tags: c#, serialization, deserialization, abstract-class, protobuf-net

`protobuf-net` latest version + C#

On deserialization of a type containing properties that are subtypes of other types , I receive error :

> could not create instance of abstract class

Inspecting my inheritance tree I don't see any abstract classes.

What could `protobuf-net` be encountering to throw this exception ?

Comment: Virtually impossible to answer without some kind of code

Comment: For us to help you, we're going to need some sort of [mcve] that reproduces the problem.